# How to write FIGURE ... under a graph/diagram and not above it

Tags: floats

Good day. This is Fomum.I have diagrams/graphs in my work that are labelled as figures. My problem is the code to make these labellings fall below the diagrams and not above them.

Comment: Welcome! Just put `\caption` where you want it. Below for below; above for above.

Comment: by default the caption appears where you put `\caption` so put it after the diagram.

Comment: Thanks for your advice David. It worked like magic

Comment: Next time please provide code, so we know exactly what you are doing.